# Insert slides from existing to a new Powerpoint in officeR package

Tags: r, powerpoint, officer

I'm trying to insert specific slides from an exiting PowerPoint into a new PowerPoint created using officeR package. Need help

I'm expecting when I run my R codes it should copy specific slides from an exiting PowerPoint and insert into new PowerPoint and add some texts.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.